# Change uploaded file name in Orbeon Forms

Tags: orbeon

When I upload a file in Orbeon I get a progress bar and then a download link with the uploaded filename (for example `sample.txt`).

Now the scenario is: when I upload any file, I just have to rename the filename based on the reference number (for example `12345`) in the same form and should be displayed as `12345.txt`.

Comment: Saha, where is the reference number in the form? Is it the value of another field you created in that form? And when should the renaming of the file happen? Right after the file has been uploaded? Also, can the reference number change? If it can, should the file be renamed at that time as well?

Comment: Yes for all the questions. The 'reference number' is input text box field in the same form. Yes the renaming should happen right after the file has been uploaded. Yes the reference can be changed and the renaming also should happen at the same time.

Comment: @avernet, any suggestions here please.